# Subquery returns more than 1 row in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1242

I am executing the following query and got the error "Subquery returns more than 1 row"

My Query is

```
SELECT pkTicketID,
       TicketReplyDateAdded,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, TicketReplyDateAdded, now()) as NumberOfDays
  FROM tickets as T
    LEFT JOIN ticket_replies as TR ON T.fkTicketReplyID=TR.pkTicketReplyID
  WHERE 1 AND T.fkEmployeeID = '4'
    AND (SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, TicketReplyDateAdded, now()) as NumberOfDays
           FROM tickets as T
             LEFT JOIN ticket_replies as TR
               ON T.fkTicketReplyID=TR.pkTicketReplyID
        ) = 7
    AND T.TicketStatus = 'Replied'
  ORDER BY pkTicketReplyID DESC
```

Thanks for your help.
Umar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this error by limiting the subquery to return only one row, like this:

```
SELECT pkTicketID,TicketReplyDateAdded,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, TicketReplyDateAdded,now()) as NumberOfDays 
FROM   tickets as T 
       LEFT JOIN ticket_replies as TR
       ON T.fkTicketReplyID=TR.pkTicketReplyID 
WHERE  1 
AND    T.fkEmployeeID = '4' 
AND    (SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, TicketReplyDateAdded, now()) as NumberOfDays 
        FROM tickets as T LEFT JOIN ticket_replies as TR 
        ON T.fkTicketReplyID=TR.pkTicketReplyID
        LIMIT 1) = 7 
AND     T.TicketStatus = 'Replied' 
ORDER   BY pkTicketReplyID DESC
```

(Added 'LIMIT 1')

Answer (score 0):

Well, this happens because your subquery returns more than one row

zerkms to the rescue

ps: it is really **A LOT** of similar questions in the right "related" bar.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to add `LIMIT 1` to your subquery. Another is to figure out if your subquery should logically be able to return more than one row and, if not, to fix it.